# Apache Camel Context Path Config

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel

I am trying to set my context path using Spring Boot and Camel with this configs:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
public class InfluencieApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(InfluencieApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```
public class MainRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        this.rest("/call-open-ai")
                .description("Calls OpenAI API")
                .post()
                .id("rest-call-open-ia")
                .description("")
                .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.off)
                .skipBindingOnErrorCode(false)
                .type(String.class)
                .outType(String.class)
                .responseMessage()
                .code(HttpStatus.OK.value()).message("Sample")
                .endResponseMessage()
                .responseMessage()
                .code(HttpStatus.GATEWAY_TIMEOUT.value()).message("Integration Timeout")
                .endResponseMessage()
                .to("direct:call-open-ai");
    }
}
```

```
public class CallOpenAISubroute extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        this.from("direct:call-open-ai")
            .routeId("callOpenAI")
            .doTry()
                .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "Entering CallOpenAISubroute")
                .removeHeaders("*")
                .process(new CallOpenAIRequest())
            .endDoTry();

    }
}
```

```
server:
  port: 8080
  context-path: /influencie/*
```

And i'm trying to call this URL:
http://localhost:8080/influencie/call-open-ai
But receiving 404....
And I also get this log when muy application is up:
`2023-09-02T13:35:59.036-03:00  INFO 10040 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''`

Comment: I think the context path value should be `context-path: /influencie` (without trailing '/*')